# How to properly display datetime64[ns] time axis in xarray plots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have a dataset which I am plotting this way

```
a = xr.open_dataset('out.nc').set_index(sSeg = 'reachID')
a.sel(sSeg = 17003601)['IRFroutedRunoff'].plot()
plt.show()
```

However, the time axis is not being plotted correctly, even though the time is in datetime64[ns] format. How can I plot the time instead?

[image]

## Data

#### print(a['time])

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 19248)>
array(['2010-06-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-06-01T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-06-01T06:00:00.000000000', ..., '2016-12-31T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-12-31T18:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-31T21:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-06-01 2010-06-01T03:00:00 ...
Attributes:
    long_name:  time
```

#### print(a)

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (sSeg: 8, sUps: 24, time: 19248)
Coordinates:
  * time               (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-06-01 2010-06-01T03:00:00 ...
  * sSeg               (sSeg) int64 17003601 17003602 17003603 17003604 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: sUps
Data variables:
    reachOrder         (sSeg) int32 ...
    reachList          (sUps) int32 ...
    listStart          (sSeg) int32 ...
    listCount          (sSeg) int32 ...
    basinArea          (sSeg) float64 ...
    upstreamArea       (sSeg) float64 ...
    instBasinRunoff    (time, sSeg) float64 ...
    dlayBasinRunoff    (time, sSeg) float64 ...
    sumUpstreamRunoff  (time, sSeg) float64 ...
    KWTroutedRunoff    (time, sSeg) float64 ...
    UpBasRoutedRunoff  (time, sSeg) float64 ...
    IRFroutedRunoff    (time, sSeg) float64 ...
```